# How to save autoKey settings?

Tags: autokey

I have installed AutoKey and remapped many keys. I want to save the settings so that in case I need to switch machines I can easily set up the new machine.

Comment: There is probaby a "File - Save" command? Or what am I missing in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I backup the ~/.config/autokey/data folder to my own .dotfiles folder.
Then

**Option 1**: in a new installation, I softlink my .dotfiles folder to ~/.config/autokey/data.

`ln -sf ~/.dotfiles/autokey/data ~/.config/autokey/data`

**Option 2:** Simply replace (Copy and Paste) the default Autokey folder with the content of the backed up folder. Disadvantage is the changes you do will not be automatically saved to your .dotfiles